# Как получить значение переменной из базового класса?

Tags: c++, классы

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {
    }

    virtual void foo() {};

    void setCoordinate(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        x1_ = x1;
        y1_ = y1;
        x2_ = x2;
        y2_ = y2;

    }



protected:
    int x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_;

private:

};

class NewClass : public MyClass
{
public:

    void foo() override {
        cout << x1_ << y1_ << x2_ << y2_;
    }

protected:


private:

};




int main() {
    int x1 = 10, x2 = 20, x3 = 30, x4 = 40;
    MyClass myclass;
    NewClass newclass;
    myclass.setCoordinate(x1, x2, x3, x4);
    newclass.foo();

}
```

Как получить значения переменной из базового класса в дочернем?

Comment: `cout << x1_ << y1_ << x2_ << y2_;`

Comment: И? Взять и получить, например, как у вас уже сделано. В чем проблема-то? В чем вопрос?

Comment: Не работает... Я вызываю сначала MyClass.setCoordinate(), затем NewClass.foo() и в foo значения переменных нулевые...

Comment: Вы уже это сделали :) Правда, в вашем случае можно обойтись и без `MyClass::`.

Comment: @danythere: Вы выдумываете. Не надо выдумывать. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6c9072714f54a49

Comment: "*Я вызываю сначала MyClass.setCoordinate(), затем NewClass.foo()*" - вы просто не сможете вызвать таким образом.... Приведите **нормальный компилируемый** код.

Comment: @AnT заняться мне больше нечем, сижу час пытаюсь понять в чем проблема) Могу скинуть полный код, запустите сами

Comment: @danythere: Правила SO требуют приведения кода, *воспроизводящего проблему*. Что такое  `MyClass.setCoordinate()` и `NewClass.foo()` - не ясно.

Comment: @danythere Не хамите. Помощь нужна вам - хотя бы поэтому будьте вежливы, если уж воспитание эту вежливость не обеспечивает...

Comment: @Harry обновил. Извините.

Comment: Скажите, если я положу деньги в кошелек жены - откуда им появиться в моем? :) Вы устанавливаете поля одного объекта, а проверяете - другого!

Comment: @Harry Плохая аналогия - возможно, у человека нет жены.

Comment: @Igor "Это никогда не рано и никому не поздно" (с) "Кавказская пленница" По счастью, у нас здесь не Америка, и неполиткорректность и нетолерантность не является преступлением :)

Comment: @Harry, жены нет, к сожалению, но аналогию понял) Можно еще вопрос?) Есть три класса, каждый наследован от другого. В "самом базовом" классе в конструкторе я присвою переменным какие-то значения, затем в его дочернем вызову конструктор базового, то если я в третьем вызову конструктор второго( т.е его базового ), то при обращении к переменной в самом дочернем классе она будет равна той, что я присвоил в самом базовом? немного запутано и тупенько, но надеюсь, вы поняли))

Comment: Как бы вы не вызывали - сначала выполнится конструктор самого базового, потом его дочернего, потом внучатого класса. Во "внучатом" классе непосредственно конструктор самого базового класса вы не вызовете. А вообще ваш пример так запутан, что лучше его сформулировать как отдельный вопрос с примером кода - чтоб стало понятно, что вы хотите.

Comment: Да, вы ответили на мой вопрос. Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете методы разных объектов.

```
int main() {
    int x1 = 10, x2 = 20, x3 = 30, x4 = 40;
    NewClass newclass;
    newclass.setCoordinate(x1, x2, x3, x4);
    newclass.foo();
}
```